# Security Concerns of Migrating from Richfaces to Primefaces

Tags: security, primefaces, jboss, jboss7.x

I have a small Richfaces web application hosted on a JBoss EAP 6.4 server.  I want to now run the app instead on a JBoss EAP 7.0 server, and modify the app to use Primefaces v6.1 instead of Richfaces.

Can anyone tell me (or make an educated guess) as to what may be some new security concerns or implications for doing so?

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think there are any?

Comment: @EJP For starters, the EL injection vulnerability in Primefaces that was recently fixed:  https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-el-injection-update/

Comment: If you read the article correctly, it was fixed 2 years ago. And that is always better than keeE using RichFaces 1.0 ;-) Questions like these are not for StackOverflow. 'Educated guessues' are not somthing you should base your choices on. Every framework always stands a chance of haveing any of the known and unknown possible vulnerabilities in it or accidentally created in a new version. So there cannot be a definite extensive/complete answer.

Comment: Oh and EAP 7.1 is already released... Better to keep up to date

Comment: "Hey, maybe you can try https://www.cvedetails.com to compare the differences"  <- is all I needed.  Thanks